# MySQL - Cannot add foreign key constraint - Latin/Cyrillic

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, cyrillic, utf8mb4

This is my last resort, since I have tried everything I could find on Google and here on Stack Overflow.

I have thoroughly searched for an answer before asking this question. I have found the people have been getting the same error message from MySQL, but their solution did **not** worked for me, because I am not doing that particular thing (different column types)  wrong.

I have a problem with foreign keys, where they **are** the same type (`varchar(xx)`, where xx is same length in both cases; NOT NULL), but still gives me an error, which is described by the PHPMyAdmin's command `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` as:

> 2015-03-24 16:04:21 66c Error in foreign key constraint of table arhiva/privilegija:
>       FOREIGN KEY (korisnik_ime) REFERENCES korisnik(ime) ,
>        FOREIGN KEY (firma_naziv) REFERENCES firma(naziv)
>       ):
>       Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the
>       referenced columns appear as the first columns, or column types
>       in the table and the referenced table do not match for constraint.

Here is my database schema, sorry for the non English names (by the way, the first time I encountered this problem the column names were in Cyrillic characters, but even after I converted them in Latin - what you are seeing here - my problem was **not** solved):

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS arhiva;
CREATE DATABASE arhiva
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
  DEFAULT COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;
USE arhiva;

CREATE TABLE `korisnik` (
  ime VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL ,
  lozinka CHAR(60) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE `firma` (
  naziv VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE `privilegija` (
  korisnik_ime VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL ,
  firma_naziv VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
  pristap CHAR(1) NOT NULL ,
  FOREIGN KEY (korisnik_ime) REFERENCES korisnik(ime) ,
  FOREIGN KEY (firma_naziv) REFERENCES firma(naziv)
);
```

Can you please guide me in the right direction of solving this problem. I thought that using Cyrillic characters was the problem, but it turns out that the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: Your DB setup is wrong and you cannot reference something that's not an index. It tells you that. You don't reference things by names, you reference them by keys. This is why your schema is wrong - you have no primary key in either table, so how can you establish referential integrity? Basically, your entire starting point and schema is wrong. CTRL + A, delete, add primary keys to tables, reference by primary keys.

Comment: N.B., I am sorry for forgetting to mention that, but I **did** tried using indices, like `id` for each of the entities. But that **didn't** help either. Again, I am asking this as a last resort, since I tried everything there is in the books and on the forums.

Comment: I'd say you made an error in concluding how this works. If you have an **integer primary key** in  your table `firma` (that means `id` column and `naziv` column), then you can reference to that very record using a reference to that primary key. That means all references to that `firma` record are done via integer. That also means your foreign key must be an integer too. It's virtually impossible that it doesn't work for you if you do it like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add PRIMARY KEY (), like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `korisnik` (
ime VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL ,
lozinka CHAR(60) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(ime)
);

CREATE TABLE `firma` (
naziv VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(naziv)
);
```

Now you have an index so the foreign key constraint should work.

Comment: I see what you are saying: not only do I need primary keys, but I can only have foreign keys that are primary keys?
For example, I can't have `id` as a primary key, but assign `naziv` as foreign key?

Comment: Well, it is at least best practice to only reference primary keys in foreign keys.

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion worked. I did have primary keys in an earlier design iteration, but somehow I have left them out this time. Silly me :D